# Efficient way to do backward Elimination in Machine Learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was working with a dataset with over 295 columns(after categorical encoding) and got an accuracy of 97.92% using a random forest regression model. I want to get rid of some features using the backward elimination method but don't want to do it manually for 295 columns. Is there any efficient way to do that?

**This is what I did**

```
x_opt = X_train[:,:] 
x_opt = np.array(x_opt, dtype=float)
ols = sm.OLS(endog = Y_train, exog = x_opt).fit() 
ols.summary()
```

But I can't figure out the maximum P value because there are 1460 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 8-9 months I found answer to this question that there is a method called f_regression in sklearn which returns p-values and I can then convert those values into a dataframe and find the max value.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html